# Process Thymeleaf variable as HTML code and not text

Tags: java, thymeleaf

I'm using Thymeleaf to process html templates, I understood how to append inline strings from my controller, but now I want to append a fragment of HTML code into the page.

For example, lets stay that I have this in my Java application:

```
String n="<span><i class=\"icon-leaf\"></i>"+str+"</span> <a href=\"\"></a>\n";

final WebContext ctx = new WebContext(request, response, 
                                      servletContext, request.getLocale());
ctx.setVariable("n", n);
```

What do I need to write in the HTML page so that it would be replaced by the value of the `n` variable and be processed as HTML code instead of it being encoded as text?

Answer (score 164, accepted):

You can use `th:utext` attribute that stands for unescaped text (see [documentation](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#unescaped-text)). Use this with caution and avoid user input in `th:utext` as it can cause security problems.

```html
<div th:remove="tag" th:utext="${n}"></div>
```

Comment: Updated link to v3 http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#unescaped-text

Comment: Does this work with Apache FOP as well while rendering a PDF. Because i don't see any change adding utext tag.

Comment: I tried this but it literally throws an error for every HTML tag I use saying it needs a closing tag, even when the closing tag is present.

Comment: Important thing to note: using utext makes you vulnerable to cross site scripting attacks. An attacker can store malicious html in your `n` variable that would get executed every time the page is rendered on your user's browser. See https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Answer (score 20):

If you want short-hand syntax you can use following:

```
[(${variable})]
```

Escaped short-hand syntax is

```
[[${variable}]]
```

but if you change inner square brackets `[` with regular `(` ones HTML is not escaped.

Example within tags:

```
<div>
    [(${variable})]
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Staring with Thymeleaf 3.0 the html friendly tag would be:

```
<div class="mailbox-read-message" data-th-utext="*{body}">
```