# Display a string that contains HTML in Thymeleaf template

Tags: java, html, spring, thymeleaf

How can I display a string that contains HTML tags in Thymeleaf?

So this piece of code:

```
<div th:each="content : ${cmsContent}">
    <div class="panel-body" sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">
        <div th:switch="${content.reference}"> 
            <div th:case="'home.admin'">
                <p th:text="${content.text}"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

//More code....
```

And at this line of piece of code `${content.text}` it literally generates this on the browser:

```
<p>test</p>
```

But I want to show this instead on the browser:

**test**

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23156585/process-thymeleaf-variable-as-html-code-and-not-string

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use `th:utext` (unescaped text) for such scenarios.

Simply change

```
<p th:text="${content.text}"></p>
```

to

```
<p th:utext="${content.text}"></p>
```

I will suggest to also have a look into [documentation here](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html) to know all about using Thymeleaf.