# Thymeleaf : display a variable containing html tags

Tags: thymeleaf

In a mail I want to display a java variable :

```
context.setVariable("content", "Hi<br>This is a test<p></p>");
```

In the mail template I do :

```
<p><span th:text="|${content}|"></span></p>
```

In the mail this is converted in :

```
<p><span>Hi&lt;br&gt;this is a test&lt;p&gt;&lt;/p&gt;</span></p>
```

How to make the variable well interpretated.

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Process thymeleaf variable as html code and not string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23156585/process-thymeleaf-variable-as-html-code-and-not-string)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `th:utext` instead of `th:text`

http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#unescaped-text