# Need display response which is a html code on the view page

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-boot

I have a response from backend which is to be displayed on my html page. I am using thyeleaf as frontend. The backend response is itself a html code. In current scenario my view is displaying that response as it is. What i am looking is to have the html response to be displayed in html format i.e. without those html,body tags etc so it looks better.

This is my html response which i need to display in html format on view.

```
<HTML> <HEAD></HEAD><BODY><PRE> Checking oracle status for instance jsx (performs a tnsping to jsx) ========================================================== jsx TNS failure - unable to test database status from server apsrs0170 Could not perform a database connection test from central server. Looks like TNS is not setup for this database. Please open up Additional Services Request for DBA group to fix the issue. ESC_SCRIPT_FAILURE
```

My html code where i need to consume this response:

```
<tr>
    <th style="vertical-align: top">Message</th>
        <td th:text="${responseMessage}"></td>
</tr>
```

Here responseMessage is the html response.

Comment: You have to display as innterHtml like this.

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23156585/process-thymeleaf-variable-as-html-code-and-not-text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try to use like this ?

```
<tr>
    <th style="vertical-align: top">Message</th>
        <td th:utext="${responseMessage}"></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Wow. I dint know it could be that easy.