# How to add a break or new line in Thymeleaf?

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

This is my code using the Thymeleaf template

```
<form>
     <label>
          <input type="checkbox" th:each="activeMeal : ${activeMeals}" th:text="${activeMeal.itemName}">
     </label>
</form>
```

This is getting generated:

[image]

I want each checkbox in a separate line. In a normal plain HTML I would use the `<br/>`  tag to create the breaks. But it does not seem to be working in inside the Thymeleaf tags.

Comment: DON'T DO THIS, but... it is possible to use `th:utext` to avoid escaping HTML in strings. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23156585/process-thymeleaf-variable-as-html-code-and-not-text). I say DON'T DO THIS because of the risks. See the note in one of the answer's comments: _"...using utext makes you vulnerable to cross site scripting attacks..."_. I imagine for that reason it may be best to *never* use the `utext` approach - even if you think your specific use case may be safe.

Answer (score 1):

```
<th:block th:each="activeMeal : ${activeMeals}">
    <input type="checkbox" name="selectedActive" id="selectedActive" th:value="${activeMeal.itemName}"/>
    <label th:text="${activeMeal.itemName}"></label>
    <br/>
</th:block>
```