# How to save HTML in Mongo and display in Thymeleaf

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm storing blog posts in mongodb. Posts can have new lines (stored as \n\r) and/or anchor tags.

```
{
    "header" : "Some header",
    "body" : "The first paragraph.\n\rThe second paragraph\n\r<a href=\"www.example.com\" title=\"Example\">Example text</a>",
    "languageCode" : "DE"
}
```

By doing this in my thymeleaf view I can display the new lines:

```
<p class="card-text" th:utext="${#strings.replace(#strings.escapeXml(blogEntry.blogPost.body),'&#10;','&lt;br&gt;')}"></p>
```

However the anchor tags are displaying as plain text.

How to format the anchor tag that comes from the controller as an actual link to another site?

Comment: Remove the `#strings.escapeXml(...)` function. Works for me without that.

Comment: Yes! It works like that. If you post it as an answer I will marked it as the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `#strings.escapeXml(...)` function.

Notes:

Using `th:text` means that any HTML in the related string will be escaped - i.e. a string such as `"...<br>..."` will be treated as a literal string. Using `th:utext` means that the string will remain *unescaped* - so any HTML tags in a string such as `"...<br>..."` will be treated as HTML.

However, by also using `#strings.escapeXml(...)`, you are reversing the effect of `th:utext` by escaping the string being processed. In this case, this is not what you want.

Be aware of the [potential risks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23156585/process-thymeleaf-variable-as-html-code-and-not-text) associated with using `th:utext`. For example, you may want to escape user-provided (i.e. untrusted) input in some other way before saving it in your data store.