# Spring Boot + Thymeleaf - using WYSIWYG, display HTML from DB

Tags: html, spring, thymeleaf

basically my problem is this: Lets for an example say that I created this text in my WYSIWYG implementation and posted it to the server

```
<p>Hello world</p>
```

But when I want to display this content using Thymeleaf it displays

```
<p>Hello world</p>
```

And I somehow need to convert it into an HTML tag. Any ideas? I've been looking but so far found nothing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Process thymeleaf variable as html code and not text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23156585/process-thymeleaf-variable-as-html-code-and-not-text)

Comment: You can use `th:utext` or an inline expression such as `[(${html})]` to display unscaped text.