# Mail template from TemplateEngine does not read html tags

Tags: java, html, template-engine

I have the following template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Template for reminder to team lead</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Hello<span th:text="${firstNameTeamLead}"></span> <span th:text="${lastNameTeamLead}">!</span> </p>
        <p></span> <span th:text="${member}"> !</span> did not:
        <span th:text="${lateSteps}"></span></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

`lateStep` is a java string containing a list some html tags to display this list with bullet points. The things is the html is not read and all I have in my mail is a chunk of content mixed with html tags like this:

```
Hello teamLeadFirstName teamLeadLastName !

memberName did not: <br /> <ul><li> fetch his food today </li><li> talk to the blacksmith </li></ul>
```

Anyone has any idea on how can I make the html tags to be read and taken into account ? Therefore, having this as a result:

Hello teamLeadFirstName teamLeadLastName !

memberName did not:

- fetch his food today
- talk to the blacksmith

Thank you for reading :D

Edit:

I am using two methods to populate the template:

- the first one is a mapper that will map a variable to its value
  ```
  private Map<String, Object> createNotificationTlVariables(Mission mission, String variablesStr) {
      Map<String, Object> variables = new HashMap<>();
      TeamLead teamLead= mission.getTeamLead();
      Member member= mission.getUMember();

      variables.put("firstNameTL", teamLead.getFirstName());
      variables.put("lastNameTL", teamLead.getLastName());
      variables.put("firstNameMember", member.getFirstName());
      variables.put("lateSteps", variablesStr);
      return variables;
  }
  ```
- The second one is a method formatting the string in question
  There, I just have a list of members and for each of them, I check the late steps of the mission that I had to the variablesStr and divide by html tags

Comment: I think you submitted your question before you were finished writing it...

Comment: It's corrected now, I was interrupted in between

Comment: Thank you for fixing your question. Can you please show us your code? How are you populating the tempate?

Comment: I edited again to add the mapping of the values !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your HTML is not valid. You have a closing span tag (`</span>`) without an opening tag. Secondly, you have a variable which I assume looks something like this:

```
String variablesStr = "<br /> <ul><li> fetch his food today </li><li> talk to the blacksmith </li></ul>";
```

You cannot use `th:text` to inject HTML. Thymeleaf is too smart and will escape any HTML special characters. This means that when you pass your string to Thymeleaf, it becomes:

```
&lt;br /&gt; &lt;ul&gt;&lt;li&gt; fetch his food today &lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt; talk to the blacksmith &lt;/li&gt;&lt;/ul&gt;
```

[You *can* use `th:utext`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23294426/5645656), but you *should* change your template to use a proper [`th:each`](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#using-theach):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Template for reminder to team lead</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p th:text="'Hello ' + ${firstNameTeamLead} + ' ' + ${lastNameTeamLead} + '!'"/>
        <p>
            <span th:text="${member} + ' did not:'"/>
            <br />
            <ul>
                <li th:each="step : ${lateSteps}" th:text="${step}"/>
            </ul>
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

And lastly, the variables in your template do not match the variables in your code. For example. your template is expecting the variable "firstNameTeamLead" while your code is providing "firstNameTL".

Here is an example of what your code should look like:

```
TeamLead teamLead = mission.getTeamLead();
Member member = mission.getUMember();

List<String> lateSteps = Arrays.asList("Finish his question", "Include his source code",
        "Specify his template-engine", "Check his variable names");

Map<String, Object> variables = new HashMap<>();
variables.put("firstNameTeamLead", teamLead.getFirstName());
variables.put("lastNameTeamLead", teamLead.getLastName());
variables.put("member", member.getFirstName());
variables.put("lateSteps", lateSteps);
```

And here is the end result:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Template for reminder to team lead</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Hello Cardinal System!</p>
    <p>
        <span>Cucumberbatch did not:</span>
        <br />
        <ul>
            <li>Finish his question</li>
            <li>Include his source code</li>
            <li>Specify his template-engine</li>
            <li>Check his variable names</li>
        </ul>
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain me this, I really appreciate that

Comment: @Cucumberbatch I hope this helps. Don't mind the teasing in my example ;)